# Which architectures to support?

Tags: packaging

I'd like to provide a "deb" package for my software, now I wonder which are the architectures to support? The goal is Ubuntu 11.10 and above. `i386` and `amd64`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`amd64` (64bit) and `i386`(32bit) are the usual ones, and the ones readily available for download on Ubuntu.com